# Retrieving a sibling xml element

Tags: xml, xelement

I have a set of xml elements that are siblings

```
<z>1</z>
<b>1</b>
<w>1</w>
<n>1</n>
<e>1</e>
<v>1</v>
```

XElement y is currently pointing to Element e. I now want to look at Element b.

The code

```
var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf("b");
```

does return a collection with just the element b.

Of course, now I need to return just the single element b. I am not always certain that Element b will be a fixed number of elements above e. I am missing something really obvious here because I have not been able with looking at a lot of good articles to figure this out.

Things I have tried:

```
var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf().First().Element("b");
var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf("b").Element("b");
var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf().Single().Element("b");
var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf().Single(x=>x.Name=="b").Element("b");
```

How do I select and return just the single element b, starting with element e?

Comment: Do you have any namespace in the xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf("b").First();
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Sequence contains no elements.

Which strikes me a little weird, because without the First(), I do get a collection that contains b. I can do a foreach loop and print the Name and Value.

Comment: @ChuckBland - I'm sure your xml contains a namespace. You must take it into account.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov - That is a reasonable thing to check but no, there is no ns use.

The ElementsBeforeSelf is working. I do get a collection and I can foreach through it to print each name. The challenge seems to be how to select the one item I want from the collection. I have tried

var y = e.ElementsBeforeSelf("qci").Single(x => (string)x.Name=="b");

but it's returning null, even though I know b is in the collection.

Comment: @ChuckBland - This is absolutely working solution if there is no namespace.

Comment: @ChuckBland This solution should work. Post more of your code and the `using` statments you're using. Another thing, which version of .Net are you using? If you create a List of any type (and populate it), can you use the First() statement or it gives you the same error?

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because...... well, it is, plus a upvote for patience. Bottom line: I had a typo when I tried his answer.

Answer (score 0):

In VB this would be

```
    'y has element e
    Dim b As XElement
    b = y.Parent.<b>.SingleOrDefault
```

The C# version should be similar.